# How to pass PowerPoint words from slides to a txt with vba?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is there a way to extract the words from the slides (titles and the rest) of a PowerPoint deck and write them to a txt file using VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is, please have a look at [this site](http://pptfaq.com/FAQ00274.htm).